# Error when looping through files and outputting separate files in R?

Tags: r, loops

I have a list of 50 text files all beginning with NEW.
I want to loop through each textfile/dataframe and run some function and then output the results via the write.table function. Therefore for each file, a function is applied and then an output should be created containing the original name with output at the end.

Here is my code.

```
fileNames <- Sys.glob("*NEW.*")

for (fileName in fileNames) {

df <- read.table(fileName, header = TRUE)

FUNCTION (not shown as this works)

...
result <-print(chr1$results) #for each file a result would be printed. 

write.table(result, file = paste0(fileName,"_output.txt"), quote = F, sep = "\t", row.names = F, col.names = T)   

#for each file a new separate file is created with the original output name retained.

}
```

However, I only get one output rather than 50 output files. It seems like its only looping through one file. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The line `result = print(chr1$results)` is producing only **one thing** (the print). You then write that to a file. If you want to write to 50 different files, then you'll need to use `lapply` and in the `result` object **have a list** with your 50 expected results

Comment: Thanks! How can I do this?

Comment: If you don't know how to produce a result list, I suggest you ask a new question indicating that you need to save **50 independent results in a list** of a function applied to 50 different sets of data.

Answer (score -1):

```
readme <- function(folder_name = "my_texts"){
  file_list <- list.files(path = folder_name, pattern = "*.txt",    
 recursive = TRUE, full.names = TRUE). 

#list files with .txt ending
textdata <- lapply(file_list, function(x) {. 
    paste(readLines(x), collapse=" "). 
  }). 

#apply readlines over the file list. 
data.table::setattr(textdata, "names", file_list) . 

#add names attribute to textdata from file_list. 
lapply(names(file_list), function(x){. 
    lapply(names(file_list[[x]]), function(y) setattr(DT[[x]], y,   
file_list[[x]][[y]])). 
  }).  

#set names attribute over the list. 
 df1 <- data.frame(doc_id = rep(names(textdata), lengths(textdata)),   
 doc_text = unlist(textdata), row.names = NULL).   

#convert to dataframe where names attribute is doc_id and textdata is text. 
  return(df1). 
}
```